# How to add buttons and textviews dynamically to a grid in android?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

This is my main activity code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainl);
    b1=new Button(this);
    b2=new Button(this);
    b3=new Button(this);
    t1=new TextView(this);
    t2=new TextView(this);
    t3=new TextView(this);
    vb.add(b1);
    vb.add(b2);
    vb.add(b3);
    vt.add(t1);
    vt.add(t2);
    vt.add(t3);
    g = new GridView(this);
    g.setNumColumns(2);
    g.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(vb,vt));
    l.addView(g);
}
```

This is the adapter class for grid.

```
  class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Vector<Button> data_b;
    Vector<TextView> data_tv;

    MyCustomAdapter() {
        data_b = null;
        data_tv = null;
    }

    MyCustomAdapter(Vector<Button> text, Vector<TextView> txt_view) {
        data_b = text;
        data_tv=txt_view;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data_b.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        return convertView;

    }
}
```

My problem is that how do I add my buttons and textviews to the grid dynamically.

Please dont tell me to use a layout and inflate it coz I am not interested in doing that way.

Comment: in `getView` method you need create one `Layout` that have one `TextView` and one `Button` that is `text.get(position)` and `txt_view.get(position)`

Comment: There is no way... you have to use layout and inflate it and return inflated View in `getView()` method of Adapter...